# How do I display menu options based on access level?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Hope that question makes sense..

Basically i'm making a surgery system for a uni assignment.

I've made a service-based-database and user table with username and passwords etc.

The login is all sorted. Console prints correct RoleType and logs user in .

I've mad an enum called RoleType which I'm trying to change based on the role the user has in the

This is where im at so far...

**Login Form**

```
    //Declare an enum to store roletypes
    public enum RoleTypes
    {
        practiceManager, 
        doctor,
        receptionist
    }

    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Try and open a connection with database and run the code
        try
        {

            //Create new instance of sql connection, pass in the connection string for BayOneSurgerySystem.mdf to connect to database.
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\davie\Documents\UniWork\Software Engineering\SurgerySystem\SurgeryDatabase\BayOneLoginSystem.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");

            //Create new instance of SQlCommand and pass in a query to be called to retrieve table data for username and passwords aswell as the connection object.
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = @username and Password = @password", conn);
            //This passes user input into @username and @password
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtBoxUsername.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtBoxPassword.Text);

            //Open connection with database
            conn.Open();

            //Create new instance of dataSet to hold the data retrieved from sql query
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            //Create new instance of DataAdpater to retrieve the data pass in Sql command
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            //using DataAdapter fill in dataSet wiht data if user input and stored data matches
            da.Fill(ds);

            //Close the connection now data table is filled with username and password
            conn.Close();

            //declare bool, true if there is a match with database and user input
            bool loginSuccess =  (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 1);


            //if login success is true then open menu
            if (loginSuccess)
            {
                //Change state of enum RoleTypes bases on result from dataSet Role column.
                Console.WriteLine(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Role"].ToString());

                try
                {
                    switch (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Role"])
                    {
                        case "Doctor":
                            {
                                RoleTypes roleType = RoleTypes.doctor;
                                Console.WriteLine("Role type chnage to" + roleType.ToString());
                            }
                            break;
                        case "Practice Manager":
                            {
                                RoleTypes roleType = RoleTypes.practiceManager;
                                Console.WriteLine("Role type chnage to" + roleType.ToString());
                            }
                            break;
                        case "receptionist":
                            {
                                RoleTypes roleType = RoleTypes.receptionist;
                                Console.WriteLine("Role type chnage to" + roleType.ToString());
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }


                Console.WriteLine("Logged in.");
                FrmMenu menu = new FrmMenu();
                this.Close();
                menu.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid username or password.", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel);
                Console.WriteLine("Not logged in");
            }

         }

        //If connection cant be opened diplsay error message and catch exception and print to console
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry can't connect");
        }
    }
}
```

}

The idea is that the public enum can be referenced in FrmMenu and different controls will be visable based on the enum.

Its just ignoring the tryCatch with the switch statement and isn't catching any exception? Any idea why? or if theres a much more efficient way of doing this?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Don't take input from a user and concatenate it into a SQL statement.  This is how **SQL Injection** attacks happen.  Don't base decisions on "UserNames".  Instead, create "Groups" (or "Roles") (like Doctors, Nurses) that contain Users and use that to decide what to show.  To figure out how to show a menu, Create a menu on your form and look at the code generated in the `FormName.Designer.cs` file, and use it as a guideline.

Comment: @Flydog57 - Which is what i've done with the login? is the '**private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnPatients;**' thats relivent? I show different buttons based on **IsInRole ==""** ? I've had a quick look is it **Role Management** I'm looking for? for setting Admin and power users etc? Thanks for you help!

Comment: I'm very serious about the SQL Injection stuff.  It's one of the most common, and most serious web vulnerabilities.  Read up on it.  Use Parameterized SQL (construct your queries using variables like `@User` and pass them in as parameters to your query).  Or, use an ORM like Dapper or Entity Framework.  You don't want the Professor to pull up your code as an example of "how not to do it"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done something like this. I have created Role & UserRole Table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Role](
    [RoleID] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [RoleName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Memo] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SYS_Role] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [RoleID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

UserRole Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserRole](
    [UserRoleID] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [UserID] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [RoleID] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_UserRole] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserRoleID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserRole]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_UserRole_REF_Role] FOREIGN KEY([RoleID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Role] ([RoleID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserRole] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_UserRole_REF_Role]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserRole]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_UserRole_REF_USER] FOREIGN KEY([UserID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([UserID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserRole] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_UserRole_REF_USER]
GO
```

On your Form, Based on your login user call the query

Comment: I've never made tables programatically, can I do it using add item > server-based database and create tables that way then running the query is the same?

Comment: Yes you can create table manually. The above sql query is to create table on your sql server (Just copy this code on SQLMS new query window and execute it.  After deploying table then you can add record in the UserRole table to  give permission. Once you done that you can call your query in form to retrieve data based on the result.